# Python/html- Combine multiple html's into one

Tags: python, html

I've written a python script to convert a text file to html file. But that is kind of useless if I can't put them all together. What I'm supposed to do is display all the reports onto the website (the server part is not my problem). Now I can convert each file to an html but I just realize it's a huge library of files. How do I combine them all?

Here's what i'm thinking how to put them together, e.g:
Say this is the homepage:

[Date](http://file://home/dates/html):
- [Report 1](http://file://home/reports/html)
- [Report 2](http://file://home/reports/html)
- [Report 3](http://file://home/reports/html)
...

Some hyperlinks like that (the links here are just fake. Just showing you what i'm thinking of)...the user will click on it to see the report. Much more organized than all the html files laying around everywhere -- This is just what i'm thinking out loud.
But the problem is how do I automatically have all the html reports combined under a certain date field.
Is there a guide for this? I'm totally lost, I don't know where to start

Comment: You **do** understand that the links are to files on your local machine, and are hence worthless to the rest of us, right?

Comment: I know. But that is just an example

Comment: An example of **what**?  Anyone who isn't physically sitting at your computer is **unable to see the html in the links that you've provided**.

Comment: For the links you could just use relative urls. We can't tell you how to split the reports if you don't show some of the data.

Comment: @JackManey I do know that. I can't show you the report, it's not on the web anywhere and I don't think it's the point. I just want to know **how to put them all together like the example**. I have one html for each report. @ F.C I don't think I need to split the reports. I just want to know how to combine all the htmls together.

Comment: Like **what example**?  Your HTML files are **unviewable** to us, therefore we can't view the example that you're talking about.  Put the HTML files up on a web server somewhere and edit the links in your question to point to the HTML on the web server.

Comment: @JackManey I think you totally misunderstand me. The layout of how to put all the htmls together is the example. what's behind those links are not the example.

Comment: Again, if we can't see the HTML, then we **cannot tell you how to put the HTML together**.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -  Probably a date field in one of those HTML files.  You know, the ones that we can't see...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams multiple reports are released at certain date. I want to organize reports in terms of date

Comment: And how are we supposed to know this date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a list of tuples in Python. Then sort them in place. Then iterate over the list and produce your homepage HTML. Below an example. You need to fill in the URLs and the date for each report (either as a date object or as a string, example: '09-12-2011')

```
report_tuples = [
    ('http://www.myreport.com/report1', report1_date_object_or_string),
    ('http://www.myreport.com/report2', report2_date_object_or_string),
    ('http://www.myreport.com/report3', report3_date_object_or_string),
]
sorted(report_tuples, key=lambda reports: reports[1])   # sort by date
html = '<html><body>' #add anything else in here or even better 
                      #use a template that you read and complement
lastDate = None
for r in report_tuples:
    if not lastDate or not lastDate == r[1]:
        html += '<h3>%s</h3>' % (str(r[1]))
    html += '<a href="%s">Your Report Title</a>' % (r[0])

return html #or even better, write it to the disk.
```

**Here some URLs that might help:**

[How to sort a list in place](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

[Python data structures in general](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html)