# How to combine multiple exported dataframes in html into one

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, styles

I have exported some sets of `Pandas DataFrame` and added some form of styling to the tables. Right now there are 76 `dataframes` that I have exported as an `HTML` file.

Right now I would like to combine them into one `HTML` file and if possible generate a clickable table of contents from those headings.

My question is kind of similar to this: [Python/html- Combine multiple html's into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572901/python-html-combine-multiple-htmls-into-one)

I tried to follow it but its quite different.

So far here's what I have done:

```
import glob

df= glob.glob("*.html")
names = [i.split(".")[0] for i in df]

html = "</head> <body> <p>Data as of 5/11/2020</p> <br><p>ABC comps</p> </body></html>"

for i in df:
     html += '<h3>%s</h3>' % (names)
     html += '<a href="%s">Your Report Title</a>' % (df)

with open("test1.html", "w") as f:
     f.write(html)
```

But this is not working. I really appreciate your help with this

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your target right, the following modifications should do the trick.

1. Add opening tag(s) to your `html` string and remove closing tags from it:

```py
html = '<html><body><p>Data as of 5/11/2020</p> <br><p>ABC comps</p>'
```

2. In the `for` loop you aren't accessing the elements of `names` and `df`. You could do it this way (I removed the `<h3>` part):

```py
for n, d in zip(names, df):
     html += f'<a href="{d}">{n}</a><br>' # Using f-string since you've tagged Python 3
```

3. Finally, add closing tags to `html`:

```py
html += '</body></html>'
```

Here's the complete code snippet.

```py
import glob

df = glob.glob("*.html")
names = [i.split(".")[0] for i in df]

# Markup without closing tags
html = "<html><body> <p>Data as of 5/11/2020</p> <br><p>ABC comps</p>" 

for n, d in zip(names, df):
     html += f"<a href="{d}">{n}</a><br>" # Using f-string since you've tagged Python 3

html += "</body></html>"

with open("test1.html", "w") as f:
     f.write(html)
```

I hope this helps!