# Combine multiple HTML files into one html file Using Python

Tags: python, html, pandas, jupyter

I have a task, I'm using jupyter and I have to **combine** or **merge** multiple html files into one html file.

Any ideas how?

I did this with excel but didn't work with html files:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

data_folder='C:\\Users\\hhhh\Desktop\\test'


df = []
for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print('Loading file {0}...'.format(file))
        df.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(data_folder , file), sheet_name='sheet1'))
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? And how your html files look like ?

Comment: I did the same but with excel like this:  import os
import pandas as pd

data_folder='C:\\Users\\hhhh\Desktop\\test'


df = []
for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
        print('Loading file {0}...'.format(file))
        df.append(pd.read_excel(os.path.join(data_folder , file), sheet_name='sheet1'))
but didnt work with html, also my html files open with google chrome

Comment: have you seen this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572901/python-html-combine-multiple-htmls-into-one Maybe it can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a task for [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You would get anything inside the `<body>` tag of each HTML document, I assume, and then combine them.

Maybe something like:

```py
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

output_doc = BeautifulSoup()
output_doc.append(output_doc.new_tag("html"))
output_doc.html.append(output_doc.new_tag("body"))

for file in os.listdir(data_folder):
    if not file.lower().endswith('.html'):
        continue

    with open(file, 'r') as html_file:
        output_doc.body.extend(BeautifulSoup(html_file.read(), "html.parser").body)

print(output_doc.prettify())
```

Comment: I've edited the above code example to ensure it runs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i faced an error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable", if  i may ask whats in html_docs?

Comment: Ah, `html_docs` is a list of HTML strings that you would get from reading HTML documents. In my little example it would be `None`, hence the error.

Comment: I've edited the example to include reading HTML files in a folder. Hope this helps! You just have to set a value for the `data_folder` variable.